# How to set sort(1) to use a custom collation?

Tags: sql, sort

I have a text file containing one record per line which I'd like to sort alphabetically, except that I want '-' to sort after '[' and ']'. (The natural sort order has '-' before the square brackets.) Is there a way to modify the collation that sort(1) uses in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to substitute a character that doesn't appear in your data, but sorts after the brackets (in some locale).

```
sed 's/-/|/g' inputfile | LC_ALL=C sort | sed 's/|/-/g' > outputfile
```

This is obviously not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 4):

You will probably want to apply one of the suggested workarounds, but the answer to your question is no(t easily).  If you want to change how `sort` sorts, and none of the special sort orders offered by the command-line options suit you, you will need to define your own locale.  See `localedef`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with perl:

```
perl -e 'print sort { (($a =~ /^-/ && $b =~ /^[\[\]]/) || ($a =~ /^[\[\]]/ && $b =~ /^-/)) ? ($b cmp $a) : ($a cmp $b) } (<>)' <filename>
```

Comment: a good example of executable line noise :-)